# ISP using PRIVATE IP's no more DYNAMIC IP's provided

Tags: ip, download, file-transfer, services, private-network

Can anyone tell me how one can still use FILE HOSTING services. As of now i can still download but the speed is like 16 to 20Kbps.
Last time can use IP Camera now IP Camera no longer works.

Anyone knows how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A number of possibilities -

1. Tell your ISP to move you off CGN (and pay for the priviledge) or
2. Change everything to IPv6 (if your ISP supports it) or
3. Find and use a VPN provider that will give you a static IP address. This is fairly common - but a different use case to typical VPNs. (Just google "VPN static IP")

There are other variants of 3 above - but they all boil down to use a middleman/proxy - and a VPN is likely the best option - especially if you can connect to it from your router.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something to create a reverse tunnel. Something like ngrok does this if you can live with the IP and port you get being fully dynamic (at least on their free tier). You could potentially automate exposing this information by updating A and SRV DNS records accordingly, but your application would need to know how to use the SRV record for port information.